# LAMP not working after php.ini change (even if resetted)

Tags: php, lamp, localhost, php.ini

My LAMP machine on Ubuntu 12.04 was working fine, then I tried to modify the `etc/php5/apache2/php.ini` file opening nautilus through the terminal with `sudo nautilus`.

I have edited this line:

```
error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_NOTICE
```

to

```
error_reporting = E_ALL
```

then in terminal `sudo apachectl restart`
and saved. But now Apache is throwing a not found error wheb I try to reach my local web sites.

I have even restarted the computer and, of course, edited back php.ini, but I'm still getting a not found error.

What is it wrong?

PS even with localhost it gives me a not found error, even if when I try `sudo apachectl start` it says `httpd (pid 1316) already running`

Comment: What's the error in your apache log file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible that apache doesn't started. The start script usually determines if an instance is running by checking for pid file - but pid file can remain existing when app crashes. Try to use `netstat -tulanp` and check for the port the apache listens on (or the name or number of apache process). If it isn|t there, the apache is probably not running at all. Then you should try to start it through `/etc/init.d/apache2` script or manually delete the pid file and starting it again.